# How to set up a further Desktop Environment with proprietary drivers on Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, desktop-environments

I like to have a second desktop environment which can be selected at the login screen. This environment shall use the proprietary nvidia driver which shall not be used on the other environments.

How can I set up such an environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desktop environment and the drivers used are not related: The drivers are chosen at system bootup and subsequently at Xserver startup time, while the desktop environment is chosen only at session start later.

To achieve what you want, you can either create different GRUB lines (don't underestimate, this might be a bit of an effort) or simply a second OS installation with the same mount for /home, thus keeping all your personal (but not system) settings.